# JavaScript array of objects showing up as empty yet it has values on extending, not able to access values

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive

I am trying to assign an array of objects to an angular custom directive, as follows

```
<div custom-directive [customDirective]="arrayOfObjects"> </div>
```

But obtaining an empty array in the directive's class, yet it contains a list of objects on expanding it on the console.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[custom-directive]'
})
export class CustomDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() customDirective;

  constructor(private elmentRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.customDirective);
  .......
  }
}
```

Unable to access the values, it looks somewhat like this

[image: emptyarray]

Comment: Please provide some more code to see what you are trying

Comment: We need a complete example to really know what is going on, but just a tip: The Chrome developer console evaluates the array contents at the time you click the arrow to open it (deferred evaluation) - the array might still be empty at the time you retreive its content in your code.

Comment: Can you provide more information related to your code, so that the problem can be figured out?

Comment: Like @Biswa has answered this is likely an async problem, the tell tale is the way Chrome is showing the array, if it wasn't `async`, Chrome would show some results before expanding, if you see results after expanding it's because this was filled in later.  `(async)`..

Comment: @TobiasSchäfer I have updated the query, I hope it helps Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to the asynchronous behavior 
Note: I believe you are getting those array of objects from an asynchronous task

check this for more info - https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular